# Virtual Products that require processing

Tags: product, order-status, virtual

I have a store that sells downloadable products (that don't require further processing) and virtual products that DO require further processing.

Downloadable products bought correctly change their status to complete.
Once a virtual product is bought I want the order status to change to "processing" or "being processed" so that we can tell that more work is needed.

Can someone recommend a way to set Virtual products to go to a custom status once invoiced but downloadable products to keep doing what they are doing?

Answer (score 2):

You could put orders **on hold** instead of creating a invoice directly.

The problem with [virtual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype#virtual) products is that they're quite stupid. Same as simple but without the physical purpose.

Or add a new status under System / Order Statusses:

- Create a new status "Being processed"
- Assign status to state new so you can put it in that status

You do this before creating a invoice offcoarse.